# Is it possible to load BigQuery with schema autodetect but modify the auto-detected schema?

Tags: google-bigquery

```
bq load --autodetect
```

is great, but sometimes the inference fails based on later data rows. I believe per the documentation autodetect uses the first 50 rows. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect

Is there a way to override one or more columns with specific types, but use autodetect for the remaining rows?

E.g. I'd like to run:

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect --schema SomeField:SomeOtherType <target table> <input ndjson>
```

And only the unspecified fields in the input source would be autodetected.

Alternatively, is there a `bq` that shows the autodetected schema without attempting to load?

My workaround to this is a bit tedious

- Load and allow bad records `--max_bad_records` into a temp table.
- Get the schema.
- Modify by hand as needed.
- Load into the real target table.

Comment: Currently, there is no feature in bq for your requirements. You can file a feature request using this BigQuery [issue tracker template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685&pli=1). Note that there are no ETAs or guarantees of implementation for [feature requests](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) but you can see all the updates there in the Issue Tracker which you have created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just found a great tool exactly for this:

https://github.com/bxparks/bigquery-schema-generator

Assuming you're using virtual env:

```
pip3 install bigquery_schema_generator
cat input-data.ndjson | ./env/bin/generate-schema --keep_nulls > ./output-schema
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON <target table> ./input-data.ndjson ./output-schema
```